# Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame by giving values for several (but not all) levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
m_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]])
test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(27), m_index)
```

I want to find all the rows for which the first two index levels are in some list of values, e.g. `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 3)]`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) on the index and then call [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
keys = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 3)]
# -1 drops the last level, so we're checking the first two only
test_df[test_df.index.droplevel(-1).isin(keys)]

          0
a 1 0.1   0
    0.2   1
    0.3   2
b 2 0.1  12
    0.2  13
    0.3  14
c 1 0.1  18
    0.2  19
    0.3  20
  3 0.1  24
    0.2  25
    0.3  26
```

Comment: God bless stackoverflow. Thank you, just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 3)]

df = test_df[test_df.reset_index(level=2).index.isin(L)]
print (df)
          0
a 1 0.1   0
    0.2   1
    0.3   2
b 2 0.1  12
    0.2  13
    0.3  14
c 1 0.1  18
    0.2  19
    0.3  20
  3 0.1  24
    0.2  25
    0.3  26
```

Comment: I like `index.droplevel` syntax a bit more but this, of course, also works, thanks.

Comment: Additionally `reset_index` creates a copy of the dataframe so it uses a little more memory than droplevel would. Not sure about performance.

Comment: @EgorIgnatenkov - No problem, then better is use `droplevel(2)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution is also possible without index manipulation. Just match the zipped tuple of index level 0 and 1 to the desired list.

```
test_df[list(map(lambda el: el in [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 3)],
                 zip(test_df.index.get_level_values(0),
                     test_df.index.get_level_values(1))))]

          0
a 1 0.1   0
    0.2   1
    0.3   2
b 2 0.1  12
    0.2  13
    0.3  14
c 1 0.1  18
    0.2  19
    0.3  20
  3 0.1  24
    0.2  25
    0.3  26
```